# How to get name of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I need to get name of current custom taxonomy in archive.php file when page is showing posts belong to the one of custom taxonomy categories.

It's easy do it in WP loop but I need get it in front of loop's body.

How could I do it?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/taxonomy-title-output?replies=7

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about when the archive.php is used as a taxonomy page.

If so, you will first need to check if the current page being viewed is actually a taxonomy page. If you don't do this check, you will get errors on pages that are not taxonomy pages, for instance date archive and category archive pages if they all make use of the archive.php template. The reason is, the queried object varies from page to page, the queried object is diffirent for a taxonomy page than for a date archive page

So you would wrap your queried object inside a `is_tax()` conditional check to make sure that the taxonomy name only displays on the taxonomy page.

To get a complete overview of [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) on a page/template, simply do the following

```
<?php
 $queried_object = get_queried_object();
 var_dump( $queried_object );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this, though I'm not sure if it will work on `archvie.php`:

`echo get_query_var( 'taxonomy', 'Not Found' );`

[A complete list of Query Vars can be found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars).

Answer (score 0):

hey by using `get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator )`

Get a list of registered taxonomy

Example-

```
$args=array(
  'name' => 'genre'
);
$output = 'objects'; // or names
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
  }
}
```

Source- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies